# How to display white space in tuple list after comma?

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to add one white space between even numbers like "(1, ),". Please find more details below:

```
L=[]
for i in range(0,100,2):
    L.append((i, ), )
print(L)

result = L

assert result[1] == (2, )
```

I would like to add a blank space character after the first comma inside this tuple list. Whenever I use '' or " " it doesn't give me satisfying final result. Could you please advice with this ?

Comment: Spacing is done in output routines, it's not part of the data.

Comment: If you want "whitespace" you can use an empty string `""`. I don't think Python has `(i, )` different from `(i)`. IE use `(i, "")`

Comment: Mr. Barmar, so sorry but I don't get it...
@Saddy If I use "", I get it: (0, '') which is not the desired result

Comment: What about uneven numbers?

Comment: @JohnAndrews The task is to filter out even :)

Comment: whatever you're actually trying to do, I can't imagine this is the best way to get it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about input a string ?

EDITED

```
L=[]
for i in range(0,100,2):
  L.append((i, ''), )

list = str(L)
print(list.replace("''",""))
```

output:

```
[(0,  ), (2,  ), (4,  ), (6,  ), (8,  ), (10,  ), (12,  ), (14,  ), (16,  ), (18,  ), (20,  ), (22,  ), (24,  ), (26,  ), (28,  ), (30,  ), (32,  ), (34,  ), (36,  ), (38,  ), (40,  ), (42,  ), (44,  ), (46,  ), (48,  ), (50,  ), (52,  ), (54,  ), (56,  ), (58,  ), (60,  ), (62,  ), (64,  ), (66,  ), (68,  ), (70,  ), (72,  ), (74,  ), (76,  ), (78,  ), (80,  ), (82,  ), (84,  ), (86,  ), (88,  ), (90,  ), (92,  ), (94,  ), (96,  ), (98,  )]
```

Comment: as I mentioned above:  If I use "", I get it: (0, '') which is not the desired result

Comment: but your result will need to be string not list to have a space like you need. python dont have a  `var = `

Comment: @matrix1395 can you use like i changed?

Comment: yess thank you so much, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some one liners:

**To filter out only even numbers**

```
[(x, "") for x in range(0,10,1) if x % 2 == 0]
```

*[(0, ''), (2, ''), (4, ''), (6, ''), (8, '')]*

**To filter out only uneven numbers**

```
[(x, "") for x in range(0,10,1) if x % 2 != 0]
```

*[(1, ''), (3, ''), (5, ''), (7, ''), (9, '')]*

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do just a simple assignment of `[(2,),(4,)]` ?

I did this and got the result:

```
>>> [(i,) for i in range(0,100,2)]
[(0,), (2,), (4,), (6,), (8,), (10,), (12,), (14,), (16,), (18,), (20,), (22,), (24,), (26,), (28,), (30,), (32,), (34,), (36,), (38,), (40,), (42,), (44,), (46,), (48,), (50,), (52,), (54,), (56,), (58,), (60,), (62,), (64,), (66,), (68,), (70,), (72,), (74,), (76,), (78,), (80,), (82,), (84,), (86,), (88,), (90,), (92,), (94,), (96,), (98,)]
```

The only way to get `[(0,  ), (2,  ), (4,  ).....]` to display would be to alter the print statement to show the data differently. However, it does not impact the way it stores the data into L.

What do you want to do with the additional space? Display or store?